# Performing a dynamic quantity of https synchronously using Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an array of URL's for which i need to perform a http.get sequentially. And, depending on the result, carry on to the next item in the array.

For example:

```
var myArray = this.myService.getUrls();
// myArray can be something like this:
// ['http://www.us.someurl.com', 'http://www.hk.anotherurl.com']
// Or...
// ['http://www.us.randomurl.com']
// Or...
// ['http://www.us.someurl.com', 'http://www.hk.notaurl.com', 'http://www.pl.someurl.com', 'http://www.in.boringurl.com]
```

When i perform a http.get on each of these, my server will respond within its data something along the line of {isReady: true} or {isReady: false}

What i want to be able to do it for each item in myArray, perform the http.get, and if the result of that individual call is isReady = true, dont perform the next http.get in the array. If isReady = false, then move on to the next URL in the array.

I have tried flatMap, but its seems i cannot get around hard coding the URLs:

```
var myArray = ['http://www.us.someurl.com', 'http://www.hk.anotherurl.com'];

this.http.get('http://www.us.someurl.com')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap(group => this.http.get('http://www.hk.anotherurl.com') )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((res) => {
       console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using a combination of `concatMap`, `filter` and `take`:

```
const URLS = ['http://www.us.someurl.com', 'http://www.hk.anotherurl.com'];

// ...
public getResponse()
{
  return from(URLS).pipe(
    concatMap(url => this.http.get<{ isReady: boolean }>(url)),
    filter(({ isReady }) => isReady),
    take(1),
  );
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbvgbu)

Comment: trying to take this one step further with the .json file as  { 
  "body": {
    "ready": false
  }
}  however whenever/wherever i modify the 'ready' property in the .ts files i get a compile error. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bfyma